# FadeOut a div tag and his content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I want to `fadeOut` a div-tag and its nested content if I click the 'delete' link.

I have written the following code:

**Controller:**

```
  respond_to :html, :js
   def destroy_attachment
   @div_id = params[:id]

   respond_to do |format|
    respond_with @div_id
   end
  end
```

**View:**

```
  <% for attachment in attachments %>
    <div class="attachment_<%= attachment.id %>">
            .....................
            ...some other content...
            .....................               
    <%= link_to "Destroy",  {controller: "topics" , action: "destroy_attachment"},
        :id => attachment.id,:remote => true, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
         :method => :post ,  class: "icon icon-del" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**destroy_attachment.js.erb :**

```
  $('.attachment_<%= @div_id %>').fadeOut("slow");
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the `selectioncall(*.attachment_<%= @div_id %>*)` in the `.js` file wrong, or something else?

Comment: `$('.attachment <%= @div_id %>').fadeOut("slow");` ?

Comment: No, the underline is needed because of the div class name "attachment_<%= attachment.id %>" I think.

Comment: have you checked that <pre>destroy_attachment.js.erb</pre> really gets rendered and that when you execute the script you are expecting really getting the result you expect? Firebug or Chromes Dev-Console are your friends for this tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found some bugs in my implementation and now it works for me, with the following code:

**Controller:**

```
def destroy_attachment
  @div_id =  params[:id]   
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= link_to "Destroy",  {controller: "topics" , action: "destroy_attachment",:id => attachment.id}, :remote => true, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :post ,  class: "icon icon-del" %>
```

Here I shifted the ":id => attachment.id" part in the braces to get access with the params method in the Controller

**destroy_attachment.js.erb:**

```
$("#attachment_<%=@div_id%>").fadeOut(150, function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```